# Spring boot testing: run script in a nested test (@Sql("/script.sql"))

Tags: java, spring, mockito, integration-testing, junit5

In my Spring boot project's test I cannot execute SQL script inside a nested class.

**Code**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SecurityTestConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "test-security-profile"})
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class MyTest{
    //...
    @Test
    @Sql("/permission.sql")
    void temp() {//here script is executed well}

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("Inner test")
    class InnerTest {
       @Test
       @Sql("/permission.sql")
       void temp() {//here @Sql throws exception}

    }

}
```

**Exception** (throws when I run the test)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute SQL scripts for test context [DefaultTestContext@406ad6d5 testClass = MyTest.InnerTest, testInstance = uz.oltinolma.producer.security.mvc.permission.MyTest$InnerTest@2a7bc16b, testMethod = temp@MyTest.InnerTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@1186374c testClass = MyTest.InnerTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5f8e8a9d, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@3cce5371, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@4f0f2942], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]: supply at least a DataSource or PlatformTransactionManager.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:203) ~[spring-test-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.executeSqlScripts(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:142) ~[spring-test-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener.java:112) ~[spring-test-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:291) ~[spring-test-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeEach(SpringExtension.java:107) ~[spring-test-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:155) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:128) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) [junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) [junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) [junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:65) [junit5-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) [junit-rt.jar:?]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) [junit-rt.jar:?]
```

Below I giving application.yml file:

```
spring:
  datasource.dbcp2:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: tester
    password: tester
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test_pg
    initial-size: 0
    max-total: 12
    max-idle: 12
  h2:
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:test_h2
      username: tester
      password: tester
      driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
      init-sql: h2.sql
```

**Datasource**

```
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "datasource")
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.dbcp2.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.dbcp2.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.dbcp2.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.dbcp2.password"));
        dataSource.setMaxActive(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-total")));
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.dbcp2.max-idle")));
        dataSource.setInitialSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.dbcp2.initial-size")));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "h2Datasource")
    public BasicDataSource h2DataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.h2.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.h2.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.h2.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.h2.datasource.password"));

        Resource initData = new ClassPathResource("scripts/h2.sql");
        DatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(initData);
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(databasePopulator, dataSource);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager tx(@Qualifier("datasource")BasicDataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager h2tx(@Qualifier("h2Datasource") BasicDataSource h2Datasource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(h2Datasource);
    }
```

Can someone explain why script execution fails when I try to run it inside a nested test class? I could think that I am missing some configuration files. However, @Sql scripts works well if I put test method directly in MyTest class.

Comment: For information: all no database nested tests work well

Comment: What happens if you copy your `@SpringBootTest`, `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`, and `@ActiveProfiles` declarations verbatim to your `InnerTest` class?

Comment: FWIW, this sort of construct seems to work against Spring Framework 5.1+, as can be seen here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/865f1f692a8bbac4f6ea3d1600ca1924c08c654a

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The failure message in the stack trace mentions:

> Failed to execute SQL scripts for test context ...: supply at least a DataSource or PlatformTransactionManager.

That last part lets me know that your `ApplicationContext` was not properly loaded for your `@Nested` test class.

Thus, the solution is to copy the annotations from the enclosing test class to the nested test class as follows.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SecurityTestConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "test-security-profile"})
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Nested
@DisplayName("Inner test")
class InnerTest {
   @Test
   @Sql("/permission.sql")
   void temp() {//here @Sql throws exception}

}
```

The reason you have to duplicate the configuration is that annotations in Spring are not *inherited* from enclosing classes.

This is a known limitation of the *Spring TestContext Framework* that may potentially be addressed in conjunction with [SPR-15366](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15366).

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation. I have tried your answer.  However, it causes another exception: ```org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'uz.oltinolma.producer.security.mvc.permission.MyTest' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}```

Comment: it is in the ```MyTest$InnerTest#temp```

Comment: That sounds like you're using Spring Framework 5.0; whereas, there was a bug fix in 5.1 that addresses this issue. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9478

Comment: I didn't really understand what happened. But after two days of trying the same code that was causing the exception above worked well. Funny, huh)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried another solution at it worked for me;
I have added some configurations on application.properties as follows:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:test-data.sql
```

BTW, the solution provided by @SamBrannen worked for me.